# Stretch button to parent container

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, layout, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to create a layout similar to telerik's [numeric updown control](http://www.telerik.com/libraries/windows_phone_8/numericupdown-1-windows-phone-control.sflb)
inside the content panel grid but I can't get the buttons to stretch in grid cells. How can I achieve this?

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" 
      Grid.Row="1" 
      Margin="12,6,12,0" 
      Height="70">
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

   <Border Grid.Column="0"
           BorderThickness="2"
           BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}">
      <TextBlock Text="Count" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                 Margin="12"/>
   </Border>
   <RepeatButton Grid.Column="1" 
                 Content="-"/>
   <RepeatButton Grid.Column="2" 
                 Content="+"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `Button` and `RepeatButton` controls have a default margin.

What you can do is edit a copy of the control template and manually set the `Margin` property to 0.

To do that, you need to open your project in Blend, then right click the Button and select Edit Template-> Edit a copy.

Then you will have to change the Margin property of the Border control from `{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}` to 0.

Here is the resulting Style, if you don't have Blend:

```
<Style TargetType="RepeatButton">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5,10,6"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="RepeatButton">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBasePressedForegroundBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" Margin="0" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0" >
                                <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Tried everything for this. Only editing in Blend fixed it up. Strange.